# Possible to upgrade the RSAT in Server 2012 R2 to manage Server 2016 properly?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2016

We recently migrated to Hyper-V Server 2016 (the non GUI version) as our hypervisor host, however, our guest VMs are still running Windows Server 2012 R2.

We found that the remote management tools (RSAT) in Server 2012 R2 has some issues when managing the Server 2016 remotely. For example, remote task scheduler management does not seem to work.

Using the newer RSAT tools in Windows 10 does work, however, it misses some features such as Windows Server Backup remote management.

Is it possible to upgrade the RSAT in 2012 R2 to a newer version to be fully compatible with Server 2016 management?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not:
Windows Task Scheduler [is not part of RSAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems)

Additionally, you will experience issues if you want to manage Hyper-V from an older version of Windows:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts#supported-combinations-of-hyper-v-manager-and-hyper-v-host-versions

Personally, I set up a server dedicated to management that runs Windows Server 2016 to manage my servers.

However, I think that you should try [Windows Admin Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-admin-center) to manage your servers using a web interface (including a web-based Task Scheduler management tool)